# Map method not working for firestore based Next app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to return a simple JSX component based on Firebase data but it doesn't seem to work. I tried returning only the component and that works perfectly. However, if I try to map it, it doesn't work. The server is returning data for sure as I could log it into the console.
I tried to set up the code in Codesandbox but that isn't being setup properly. Any help is much appreciated.

This is my Github link: https://github.com/servesh-chaturvedi/Chat-App-with-firebase

The current code in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-morning-clnrp?file=/components/Sidebar.js

```
{chatSnapshot?.docs.map((chat) => {
  <Chat key={chat.id} id={chat.id} users={chat.data().users} />
 })}
```

Comment: Please include the code you're having difficulty with in the question. Providing links to off-site code is not helpful. We also don't want to debug your entire project just to understand the question. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah I tried setting up the codesandbox but somehow it didn't get past the login component there. But thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an arrow function, the default behavior is to return whatever is to the immediate right of the arrow, such that:

```
const returnsHello = () => 'Hello'
returnsHello() //'Hello'
```

But when you want to use the arrow function with a block of code like you're doing with the curly braces, the implied return is dropped and must be made explicit. Here's an edit of your code that should work, assuming you don't have other issues.

```
{chatSnapshot?.docs.map((chat) => {
 return <Chat key={chat.id} id={chat.id} users={chat.data().users} />
 })}
```

This will iterate through each element of your array, and return a new array with Chat components using the array values.

Comment: This is such a silly and embarrassing mistake from my side. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The only reason I caught it is because I've made the mistake myself dozens of times! Depending on your code editor, you may be able to add a linting rule to show functions without return statements so you can catch it quicker next time, that's what I did

Comment: I'll definitely check on that